# ASP.NET WEB FORMS Remover um <p> e seu conteúdo de uma DIV

Tags: asp.net, webforms, div

Eu tenho diversas DIVS que contém um < p >&nbsp ;< /p >. Como removo esse parágrafo com espaço no CodeBehind? (Sem usar JS ou JQuery)

Comment: Porque quer remover isso no CodeBehind? Explique melhor sua pergunta. Tem algum exemplo de código?

Answer (score 0):

Já descobri.

```
 (OBJETO).Text = Regex.Replace((OBJETO).Text, "<p>&nbsp;</p>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

;)

Comment: Leandro se explicares a resposta pode ser que outros com o mesmo problema consigam aprender também.